# bash: how to avoid a command from being used and run

Tags: bash, security, terminal, zsh

**Is there a way to prevent a bash or zsh terminal to run a specific command?**

Let's say I want to prevent running by mistake a `rm` on directory `~/foo`. So I want to prevent the following command to be run:

```bash
rm -r ~/foo
```

Another example much broader:

```
mycustomcommand -param1 foo
```

In the example above, `foo` can change, but every time one tries to run:

```
mycustomcommand -param1 anything
```

It should block and fail.

Therefore, if I run the above command in my local terminal (or a server, etc) the command is blocked (and even better with an error/warning message).

How can we achieve such behavior?

Comment: There are many ways to delete something. You can move it first (rename) and delete. You can delete with relative or absolute paths... Catching them all will be difficult. Why not protecting the directory against modifications (`chmod -R a-w ~/foo`)?

Comment: This example above was just an example. The question is broader: how to protect a command to run. `mycommand params`. I am thinking maybe an alias to itself. But mot sure it would work.

Comment: No, it would not because `command mycommand params` would bypass the alias or function lookup. Same with `\mycommand` that would bypass the alias.

Comment: Great point. However, let's say I need something much more simpler: just protecting myself from mistakenly running some command. Should it work aliasing itself? Or maybe a better solution?

Comment: Oh, if there are no security issues just alias to `echo "forbidden"`. Or define a function with the same name: `mycommand(){ `echo "forbidden"; }`.

Comment: Thanks. And if need something much more robust?

Comment: Define _more robust_...

Comment: A command (or a command with specified options) is not allowed at all for specific users or in a specific shell.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246075/discussion-between-renaud-pacalet-and-yfl).

Answer (score 0):

## Linux permissions

Linux has users, groups, file permissions and file attributes to restrict what may be done with the each file and this is the simple and reliable way.

E.g. When file cannot be deleted, even by root (without resetting the attributes), set:

```bash
$ sudo chattr +i cannot_delete_me.txt
$ rm cannot_delete_me.txt
rm: cannot remove 'cannot_delete_me.txt': Operation not permitted
```

To disallow removing the file without a question by non-root account, it is enough to set corret file permissions:

```bash
$ chmod a-w cannot_delete_me.txt
$ rm cannot_delete_me.txt
rm: remove write-protected regular empty file 'cannot_delete_me.txt'?
# Now it is possible to delete it when typing y + enter
```

To disallow deleting a file by non-root account without changing the permissions, change parent directory write permission:

```bash
$ mkdir foo && cd foo
$ touch cannot_delete_me.txt
$ chmod a-w .
$ rm cannot_delete_me.txt
rm: cannot remove 'cannot_delete_me.txt': Permission denied
```

## Shadowing the command name

Any command may be called in many ways, different paths, so it is **not** secure to shadow command name:

```bash
$ function rm { echo "I am dummy rm function. I will not remove: $1"; }
$ export -f rm
$ rm foo
I am dummy rm function. I will not remove: foo
/bin/rm foo # It will delete foo
```

## Use Docker

When you don't trust the script you are calling, call it inside the Docker container. It allows binding directories from host system with e.g only read permissions, so you are sure that given script will access things you allowed.

Inside the Docker image, you also may replace unwanted Linux commands.
Let's see the example:

```bash
$ mkdir my_script_environment_image && cd my_script_environment_image
```

Create `Dockerfile` inside `my_script_environment_image` directory:

```
FROM debian:latest

RUN echo '#/bin/bash \n\
echo "This is a dummy rm. I will not remove: $1" \n\
' > /bin/rm
```

Build the image with defined name:

```bash
sudo docker build --tag my_script_environment .
```

Call a temporary (with `--rm`) container which will run shell or your script.

```bash
sudo docker run -it --rm my_script_environment /bin/bash
root@f6d62a754b38:/# touch my_file.txt
root@f6d62a754b38:/# rm my_file.txt 
This is a dummy rm. I will not remove: my_file.txt
```

So your command has been replaced by custom command and whole Docker environment.

In practice, I'm using Docker to control the scope of script/application effects.